# MYSQL() function not working in asterisk dialplan

Tags: asterisk

```
exten => 8367,1,MYSQL(connect connid SERVERIP cron 1234 asterisk)
exten => 8367,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} select\ comments\ from\ 
         vicidial_list\ where\ list_id=\5555\ and\ phone_number=\${EXTEN:2}\ 
         order\ by\ lead_id\ desc\ limit\ 1\)
exten => 8367,n,MYSQL(Fetch vdp_tmp ${resultid} comments)
exten => 8367,n,MYSQL(Clear ${resultid})
exten => 8367,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid}))

exten => 8367,n,NoOp(${comments})

exten => 8367,n,Platback(/tmp/${comments})

exten => 8367,n,Hangup()
```

##  THIS IS NOT WORKING IN ASTERISK 1.8.32 PLEASE SUGEST ME I AM GETTING ERROR AS 
   ##WARNING[25354]: pbx.c:4706 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'MYSQL' for extension (default, 8367, 4)

Answer (score 0):

Use func_odbc or REALTIME

MYSQL function outdated in 1.4. You can compile it upto 14.*, but by default it turned off.

Anyway func_odbc work simpler and not require check for connection.

Comment: thanku very much for your reply ,i want to connect from one server to other server for feteching values is it possible with func_odbc

Comment: Any query possible for mysql possible via func_odbc. Also possible connect to any other db with unixodbc driver(postgress,oracle,microsoft etc etc).

Comment: can you please provide me one example extensions to connect other db and fetech data

Comment: i find a solution that i wrote AGI script for that thanku

Comment: AGI script spwan new process. Also it re-interpret your code file if you use interpretor like perl. It is bad idea use agi if you just need one value from db(no complex logic).